# Setting Bugsnag configuration options in code

Tags: asp.net, bugsnag

In the [documentation](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/dotnet/web-api/configuration-options/#notify-release-stages) it says that I can do the following in code to further configure my integration:

> Each key provides an **in code** example and a config file example.

```
configuration.ReleaseStage = "development";
```

What I am trying to do is:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var configuration = Bugsnag.ConfigurationSection.Configuration.Settings;
    configuration.ReleaseStage = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"];
    config.UseBugsnag(configuration);
}
```

However, the configuration properties are read-only (don't have setters).

The alternative is to add the configurations to the Web.config:

```
<bugsnag apiKey="your-api-key" releaseStage="development">
```

The problem is that I am reading my environment from the AppSettings and therefore cannot do it this way.

Is it possible to do the configuration **in code** and if so, how?

UPDATE: Since posting the question I have found the [issue](https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-dotnet/issues/93) on GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the GitHub issue it seems as if this isn't possible so I used the [work around](https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-dotnet/issues/93#issuecomment-396377030) suggested by one of the project's contributors.

> The only work around I can suggest right now is to use the core Bugsnag nuget package...

I removed all the 'old' code, uninstalled all the NuGet packages except for the base Bugsnag and added the following code to the `OnException` override method where I had been logging exceptions up until now.

```
var configuration = new Configuration("API_KEY")
{
    ReleaseStage = myReleaseStage
};
var client = new Bugsnag.Client(configuration);
client.Notify(new System.Exception("Error!"));
```

This worked and errors are now logged along with the environment in which they occurred. My next step will be to refactor this work around so that `client` is available globally but for now this solves my **in code** problem.

Answer (score 0):

From Bugsnag's latest Go documentation, you can [programmatically set the release stage](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/dotnet/web-api/configuration-options/#release-stage). In your example, it would look like this:

`configuration.ReleaseStage = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"];`